# Google Maps API for my image

Tags: google-maps

I have my own custom technology map and I was looking to integrate the image with the Google Maps API to provide a richer Google Map-like experience for navigating around my material.

Can anyone provide some thoughts on how best to do this?  What steps do I need to look at in order to use my custom image with the Maps API?  Is it even possible.

Similar examples would be what Google did for the Moon or Mars - but is this approach open to others to do?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to create a Custom Map Type with a Custom Projection:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#CustomMapTypes
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#Projections

All the information you need is there in the documentation.